# How to edit NSMutableArray in other Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, exc-bad-access

I have NSMutableArray in "AppDelegate.h"

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *myArray;
```

and "AppDelegate.m"

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    return YES;
}
```

In UITableViewController i add objects in NSMutableArray

```
- (IBAction)AddComment:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    SectionObject *sectionObject = [[SectionObject alloc] init];

    sectionObject.id = (NSInteger*)appDelegate.myArray.count;
    sectionObject.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"New object %i",appDelegate.myArray.count];

    [appDelegate.myArray addObject:sectionObject];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

To edit the object I pass other UITableViewController objects from the array controller

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    UINavigationController *navController = segue.destinationViewController;
    ExerciseTableViewController *controller = (ExerciseTableViewController *)navController;

    controller.contactdb = [appDelegate.myArray objectAtIndex:[[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row]];
}
```

When i am going back to write

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self] == NSNotFound) {

        self.contactdb.name = self.nameTextField.text;
    }

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

I receive an error  'EXC_BAD_ACCESS'. If i not edit `self.contactdb.name`, I dont have error. How can i edit object in other controller?

Comment: This sounds like a terrible way to structure your app

Answer (score 0):

Your if-statement:

```
  if ([self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self] == NSNotFound)
```

basically guarantees your view controller has already been removed from the navigation stack. That's why you get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when trying to access properties from that view controller. You should place your `self.contactdb.name = self.nameTextField.text` statement somewhere else.